# How to add an entry to an external JSON array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm working on a discord bot and I was searching how to add an entry to a JSON array, but I couldn't find an answer.

I want

```
{"blacklisted": ["test1", "test2"]}
```

to become

```
{"blacklisted": ["test1", "test2", "test3"]}
```

This is what I tried

```js
const file = require('./numbers.json');
var fs = require('fs');
var blacklisted = file.blacklisted
blacklisted.push('test3');
var logger = fs.createWriteStream('numbers.json')
    logger.write(`{"blacklisted":[${blacklisted}]}`)
```

but it gives me this:

```
{"blacklisted":[test1,test2,test3]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this,

```
const file = require('./numbers.json');
var fs = require('fs');
var blacklisted = file.blacklisted
blacklisted.push('test3');
var logger = fs.createWriteStream('numbers.json')
    logger.write(JSON.stringify(file))
```